# dealing with redirect domains in StormCrawler

Tags: stormcrawler

I am working on StormCrawler based project. One of our requirements is finding domains which redirected to another domain. In StormCrawler, each redirected URL considered as a depth in crawling. For example, for a domain with two redirected steps, we need to crawl with depth=2. How can I resolve all redirected domains without considering the **depth** in the crawler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters do not distinguish between URLs found from redirections and those coming from links in a page. You could simply deactivate the depth-based filter and instead have a custom parse filter to restrict the outlinks if necessary.

Comment: Why not modify the MaxDepthFilter: if the source metadata includes a key `_redirTo`, do not increment the depth for the outlink.

Comment: Where can I prevent the depth increment in the StormCrawler? MaxDepthFilter?

Comment: Also, I found some client-side redirection checking inside JSoupParserBolt class.

Comment: custom parse filter or custom depth filter?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified MaxDepthFilter as follows:

```
public class MaxDepthFilter implements URLFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MaxDepthFilter.class);

    private int maxDepth;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(Map stormConf, JsonNode paramNode) {
        JsonNode node = paramNode.get("maxDepth");
        if (node != null && node.isInt()) {
            maxDepth = node.intValue();
        } else {
            maxDepth = -1;
            LOG.warn("maxDepth parameter not found");
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public String filter(URL pageUrl, Metadata sourceMetadata, String url) {
        int depth = getDepth(sourceMetadata, MetadataTransfer.depthKeyName);
        
        boolean containsRedir = containsRedirect(sourceMetadata, "_redirTo");
        
        // is there a custom value set for this particular URL?
        int customMax = getDepth(sourceMetadata,
                MetadataTransfer.maxDepthKeyName);
        if (customMax >= 0) {
            return filter(depth, customMax, url);
        }
        // rely on the default max otherwise
        else if (maxDepth >= 0) {
            if(containsRedir)
                return url;
            else
                return filter(depth, maxDepth, url);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private String filter(int depth, int max, String url) {
        // deactivate the outlink no matter what the depth is
        if (max == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (depth >= max) {
            return null;
        }
        return url;
    }
    

    private int getDepth(Metadata sourceMetadata, String key) {
        if (sourceMetadata == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        String depth = sourceMetadata.getFirstValue(key);
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(depth)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(depth);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    
    private boolean containsRedirect(Metadata sourceMetadata, String key) {
        if (sourceMetadata == null) {
            return false;
        }
        String redir = sourceMetadata.getFirstValue(key);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(redir)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Does it works properly or trapping in an infinite loop?